# Filter custom comparable class by using operators in DataView.RowFilter

Tags: c#, csv

One column in a CSV file contains fractions. Currently, the file is read into a `DataTable` using a custom `Fraction` class that implements `IComparable` and the comparison operators. I want to be able to use a `RowFilter` such as `"Fraction > 1/2"`. Trying this results in `Cannot perform '>' operation on WindowsFormsApplication1.Fraction and System.Double` even though Fraction implements `IComparable` and defines the `>` operator. How do I solve this, or what workaround are there?

Sample CSV file

```
1/2
1/3
2
0
1
```

Reading the CSV file

```cs
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\data.csv");
parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
parser.SetDelimiters(",");
DataTable data = new DataTable();

data.Columns.Add("Fraction", typeof(Fraction));

while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    string[] input = parser.ReadFields();
    object[] output = new object[input.Length];
    output[0] = new Fraction(input[0]);
    data.Rows.Add(output);
}
```

This is what I would like to do after reading the CSV file. However, it results in `Cannot perform '>' operation on WindowsFormsApplication1.Fraction and System.Double`.

```cs
DataView matches = new DataView(data);
matches.RowFilter = "Fraction > 1/2";
dataGridView1.DataSource = matches;
```

`Fraction` class

```cs
class Fraction : IComparable
    {
        private int n;
        private int d;

        public Fraction(string value)
        {
            try
            {
                n = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                d = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                n = Convert.ToInt32(value.Split('/')[0]);
                d = Convert.ToInt32(value.Split('/')[1]);
            }
            Reduce();
        }

        private void Reduce()
        {
            int gcd = GCD(n, d);
            n = n / gcd;
            d = d / gcd;

            if (d < 0)
            {
                n = -1 * n;
                d = -1 * d;
            }
        }

        private static int GCD(int a, int b)
        {
            return (b == 0) ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
        }

        private double ToDouble()
        {
            return (double)n / d;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return n + ((d == 1) ? "" : "/" + d);
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Fraction f = (Fraction)obj;
            return this < f ? -1 : this > f ? 1 : 0;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Fraction)
            {
                Fraction f = (Fraction)obj;
                return n == f.n && d == f.d;
            }
            else if (obj is int)
            {
                int i = (int)obj;
                return n == i && d == 1;
            }
            else if (obj is double)
            {
                double x = ToDouble();
                double y = (double)obj;
                return !(x < y || x > y);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return n.GetHashCode() * 17 + d.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Fraction a, Fraction b) { return a.Equals(b); }
        public static bool operator !=(Fraction a, Fraction b) { return !a.Equals(b); }
        public static bool operator <(Fraction a, Fraction b) { return a.n * b.d < b.n * a.d; }
        public static bool operator >(Fraction a, Fraction b) { return a.n * b.d > b.n * a.d; }
        public static bool operator <=(Fraction a, Fraction b) { return a.n * b.d <= b.n * a.d; }
        public static bool operator >=(Fraction a, Fraction b) { return a.n * b.d >= b.n * a.d; }

        public static bool operator ==(Fraction a, int b) { return a.Equals(b); }
        public static bool operator !=(Fraction a, int b) { return !a.Equals(b); }
        public static bool operator <(Fraction a, int b) { return a.n < b * a.d; }
        public static bool operator >(Fraction a, int b) { return a.n > b * a.d; }
        public static bool operator <=(Fraction a, int b) { return a.n <= b * a.d; }
        public static bool operator >=(Fraction a, int b) { return a.n >= b * a.d; }

        public static bool operator ==(Fraction a, double b) { return a.Equals(b); }
        public static bool operator !=(Fraction a, double b) { return !a.Equals(b); }
        public static bool operator <(Fraction a, double b) { return a.n < b * a.d; }
        public static bool operator >(Fraction a, double b) { return a.n > b * a.d; }
        public static bool operator <=(Fraction a, double b) { return a.n <= b * a.d; }
        public static bool operator >=(Fraction a, double b) { return a.n >= b * a.d; }

        public static implicit operator Fraction(string s) { return new Fraction(s); }
        public static implicit operator string(Fraction f) { return f.ToString(); }
        public static implicit operator double(Fraction f) { return f.ToDouble(); }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Linus, I would be glad to help you if you detail a bit more the main purpose of your action: what will you do with the results, etc.
I have several ideas and would like to offer a good one!

Comment: I want to "search" CVS files using a filter entered in a `TextBox` and then show the results in a `DataGridView`. This is strictly for my own use. The problem with these CVS files is that they contain columns with types (such as the aforementioned fractions) that need custom sorting but should also be easily filterable, preferably using the comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `==`, etc). There are also columns that contain mostly integers but also some strings. These should also be filterable using the the comparison operators (strings could be consider to come after integers in these columns).